# Stripe Store Custom Account Balance in Variable

Tags: node.js, swift, stripe-payments

I was wondering if it is possible to store a Stripe Custom account balance into a variable to pass around?

Basically, I can retrieve my account balance with the `stripe.balance.retrieve({})` call, but is it possible to take the `amount` value this call returns and store it separately into a variable?

Stripe documentation doesn't really point to anything specific about this method approach

**Node.js GET Request**

[image: node]

**Swift GET call**

[image]

**Swift Console Results**

[image: swift console]

I see the movement now, properly using the Promise library. Is it at all possible to grab that `amount` value that's passed in the third picture?

Comment: Hi @LameBanana, I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but since `stripe.balance.retrieve({})` is a `Promise` in node js, you could do `cont balance = await stripe.balance.retrieve()` and pass around `balance` for consuming purpose

Beware that since the balance might change if there is any new transactions in the stripe account, the balance data might not be the latest when you `store` it in DB for later consumption

Comment: @wsw I added a couple of screenshots. I see the movement of the values now. Is it at all possible to get that `amount` value that's being passed in the third image? I'm trying to display this on my Swift frontend to a user. Thank you for your help so far!!